# Difference between 2 timestamps in days from MySQL table with user session login

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure this out myself. I understand a few things of coding but I'm nowhere good. Well currently I have a chat website where you can purchase a premium membership, I want to display the amount of days that are left until this membership is expiring for the currently logged in user.

My 2 dates for activation and expiration is stored as timestamps.

This is my try at making this but it did not work:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT timestamp_activated, timestamp_expire FROM user_subscriptions WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$datetime1 = new DateTime('. $row["timestamp_activated"]. ');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('. $row["timestamp_expire"]. ');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%a');

     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You have my sympathies but 'does not work' is not very usefull. Please explain what you expected to happen and what happened.

Comment: you're obviously mixing different MySQL APIs. `WHERE id = :id` is PDO. It does not work with `mysqli_`.

Comment: I want it to display the days remaining of the premium membership.

Comment: *Hello!!* - why is `WHERE id = :id` that in there? You realize that does NOT, I repeat...... does NOT work with mysqli_. Or, did you just write that "just cuz"? I don't seem to be getting through anyone here.

Comment: I had 2 different codes which I tried replacing a few things in to make this work and one was PDO and another was MySqli, I really am not a coder so I tried my best to make it work.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to post in my stackoverflow code but above the $sql = select i had  $user = $_SESSION['user']['id'];

Comment: @Maichel: if the above question is missing code, please edit it, rather than adding new information in comments. Would you do that now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this in your MySQL query by using [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, timestamp_activated, timestamp_expire) AS daysRemaining
FROM user_subscriptions
WHERE id = :id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `I want to display the amount of days that are left until this membership is expiring for the currently logged in user` ... how does this answer not address this question?